# Invalid conversion between the same types

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have a function which converts the elements of a vector to a string separated by comma. I want this function to work for numeric values as int, float or double etc. so I have made the function to receive a vector of templates:

```
template <typename T>
std::string ConvertToString(std::vector<T> elements)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.size()-1; i++)
    {
        stream << elements[i];
        stream << ",";
    }
    stream <<elements[elements.size()-1];
    return stream.str();
}
```

Then I declare and populate a vector:

```
std::vector<int> values;
values.push_back(1);
values.push_back(2);
values.push_back(3);
```

And try to call the function:

```
std::string convertedString = ConvertToString(values);
```

Now on the call of the above function line I receive the following error :

> error C2664: 'ConvertToString' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>'

I do not understand why do I get this error since the types mentioned are the same. Can somebody explain me where am I wrong and how could I make the function call work?

Thank you very much!

**Edit:**

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

My full code is this:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>

std::string ConvertToString(std::vector<std::string> strings);

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    values.push_back(1);
    values.push_back(2);
    values.push_back(3);
    values.push_back(4);
    values.push_back(5);

    std::string convertedValues = ConvertToString(values); //here the error occurs

    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
std::string ConvertToString(const std::vector<T> elements)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.size()-1; i++)
    {
        stream << elements[i];
        stream << ",";
    }
    stream <<elements[elements.size()-1];
    return stream.str();
}
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/igVWQS) with what you posted (at least with g++)... You probably need to show a bit more (and tell us which version of VS you are using).

Comment: Can't reproduce with VS2015, VS2013, and VS2005

Comment: @Holt I have updated with the entire code, I don;t know what is still wrong for me.

Comment: @Danh thank you for the information, I have added the complete code example, can you try again now?

Comment: This code makes an compile error

Comment: Line 6, change the declaration from `std::string ConvertToString(std::vector<std::string> strings)` to `template <typename T> std::string ConvertToString(const std::vector<T> elements)`

Comment: @Danh thank you very much, I have missed this declaration!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write this:

```
std::string ConvertToString(std::vector<std::string> strings);
```

...before `main`, you are declaring a function `ConvertToString` that takes a `std::vector<std::string>` and return a `std::string`, so when you try to call it inside `main` with a `std::vector<int>` it obviously does not work.

The compiler does not see the templated version of `ConvertToString` in `main`, so it cannot call `ConvertToString(std::vector<int>)`. Change the first declaration of `ConvertToString` to:

```
template <typename T>
std::string ConvertToString(const std::vector<T> elements);
```

And as already mentioned by other answers, you should pass by const reference rather than by value:

```
template <typename T>
std::string ConvertToString(std::vector<T> const& elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is valid C++03 so is a compiler bug or, more likely (dare I way), a malformed example. (Consider building an example from `int main()` and submit to the compiler vendor).

Luckily a workaround is available which will be much better anyway. Write

`template <typename T>
std::string ConvertToString(const std::vector<T>& elements)`

i.e. pass the parameter by `const` reference, which will also obviate a deep copy of the vector.